Is it possible to access / read all incoming notifications on an android device using a Progressive Web App
I'm trying to create a Progressive Web App that is able to read all incoming notifications on my phone. The aim is to create a sort of automated journal that captures my activity throughout the day.
Is this possible using Web Apps? Or will I have to switch to a native solution?
I've done some basic searching online. I've seen some solutions for native android apps, but I couldn't find any method to achieve this from a PWA.

Correct. It is not possible to monitor all of the notifications on a phone without being a Java/Kotlin app running on the device.
If you checked the Android documentation for NotificationListenerService you will see that an additional Java/Kotlin Android app permission/configuration required for operation.
Given that Progressive Web Apps are supposed to be run in a browser sandbox I'm not aware of any Javascript Web API allowing such behavior.
